# Organize Imports puts exports on single line

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Settings `"source.organizeImports"` to `true` automatically puts exports onto a single line.

```
export {
    Core,
    TokenSymbol,
    Token,
    TokenType,
    TypeError,
    TOKEN_TYPE_MAP,
    SymbolError,
    VALUE_TOKEN_TYPES
};
```

is updated to:

```
export {Core, TokenSymbol, Token, TokenType, TypeError, TOKEN_TYPE_MAP, SymbolError, VALUE_TOKEN_TYPES};
```

Interestingly enough, it doesn't happen with `export default`

```
export default {
    Core,
    SymbolError,
    TOKEN_TYPE_MAP,
    TokenSymbol,
    TokenType,
    TypeError,
    VALUE_TOKEN_TYPES,
};
```

this stays multi-line.

Btw I'm talking about "code actions on save" if that helps

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll": true,
    "source.organizeImports": true,
}
```

```
VS-Code Version: 1.44.0
Operating System: Ubuntu Linux
```

Comment: Please check [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-typescript-tslint-plugin/issues/51), there are a lot of simillar problems related to this two options used together

Comment: This issue seems to be closed.... and I didn't see anything about changing from multi-line to single line only the comment "disrespecting line length". I sadly did not find any issues related to "vs-code multiline export" after googling for 10mins. And I am not using `tslint` but `eslint` where I don't think I have rules regarding this. The issue has been closed singe 2 years ago so I am not hoping on any fix...

Comment: For everyone that's facing the same issue, this seems to be related to this: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22991